# clockpicker - jQuery Format Time

Tags: jquery, momentjs, clockpicker

I need to format time, for example I have a value `01:05` I need to add `am` or `pm` to time.

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    afterDone: function() {            
       var time = $('#time').val();            
       console.log(moment(time ).format('h:mm a'));      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should on the twelve hour format, bydeafult it is false, use like this

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    twelvehour: 'true',
    afterDone: function() {            
        var time = $('#time').val();            
        console.log(moment(time ).format('h:mm a'));      
    }
});
```

Comment: I got error Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. Also I just need to add am or pm to date.

Comment: I do not need to add twelvehour mode. I need to get the #time value (01:05) in a variable and format it adding "01:05 am".

Answer (score 0):

Just use moment parsing with format, see [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), in your case use `moment(time, 'hh:mm')` instead of `moment(time)`

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    afterDone: function() {            
        var time = $('#time').val();            
        console.log(moment(time, 'hh:mm').format('hh:mm a'));      
    }
});
```